# How to export string data to pdf format in .Net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net

How to export string data to pdf format in .Net Core MVC. Please anyone help me for export the data in pdf format in .net core.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to tap into the Response during OnResultExecuting and replace the Filter property with something that stores the resultant HTML in a MemoryStream. Then you could clear the Response during OnResultExecuted and replace it with the results of your PDF conversion. I'm not sure that this would be better than just getting the HTML from the URL, though.

eg =

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication2.Models
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}



 public ActionResult GetPersons()
        {
            List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
            persons.Add(new Person() { Age = 29, Name = "Rami1", Email = "Rami1@abc.com" });
            persons.Add(new Person() { Age = 28, Name = "Rami2", Email = "Rami2@abc.com" });
            return View(persons);
        }

@model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Models.Person>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetPersons";
}

<h2>GetPersons</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```